# confusing issue xml to json (php)

Tags: php, json, xml

I looked up all resources about this, and I usually use the json_encode method to covnert xml to json or array, but it's not working in this specific case, and it's really confusing, the var_dump is returning empty results always (this actually: string(2) "{}")!

the code is:

```
       $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
        if ($xml === FALSE) {
            throw new Exception('Failed to load XML string.');
        }

        $xml_array = json_encode($xml);
        var_dump($xml_array);
```

and the xml is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetTicketTypeListResult xmlns="http://vista.co.nz/services/WSVistaWebClient.DataTypes/1/">
         <Result>OK</Result>
         <DatasetXML>
            <NewDataSet>
               <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
                  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                     <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                           <xs:element name="Table">
                              <xs:complexType>
                                 <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="IsPaid" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="AvailableOnSalesChannel" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="IsDisplayedStandard" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="IsLoyaltyOnly" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="OrderPricesBy" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="TicketHasBarcode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Cinema_strID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Session_strID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="AreaCat_strCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="AreaCat_strSeatAllocationOn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Cinema_strID1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_strTicket_Type_Code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_strTicket_Type_Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_strGroup_Code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_intTicket_Price" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_strChild_Ticket" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="AreaCat_strCode1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="AreaCat_intSeq" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_strTicket_Type_Description_2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_strPackage" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="TType_strAvailLoyaltyOnly" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="TType_strHOCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_strRedemption" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_strComp" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="TType_strSalesChannels" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_strATMAvailable" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="TType_strShowOnPOS" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_intSurcharge" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="TType_intBarcodeMaxRepeats" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="TType_strMaxRepeatsCycle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="TType_strLongDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="TType_strLongDescriptionAlt" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="TType_strMemberCard" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="TType_strAvailRecognitionOnly" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="HOPK" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="AreaCat_strDesc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="AreaCat_strDescAlt" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="MMC_strName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_strIsTicketPackage" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="LoyaltyRewardTicket" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="LoyaltyTicketName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="LoyaltyTicketDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="LoyaltyTicketMessageText" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="OrderTicketsBy" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="TicketCategory" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_strLoyaltyRecognitionID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_intLoyaltyDisplayPrice" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_intLoyaltyPriceCents" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_intLoyaltyPointsCost" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                    <xs:element name="Price_intLoyaltyQtyAvailable" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                 </xs:sequence>
                              </xs:complexType>
                           </xs:element>
                        </xs:choice>
                     </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
               </xs:schema>
               <Table>
                  <IsPaid>1</IsPaid>
                  <AvailableOnSalesChannel>1</AvailableOnSalesChannel>
                  <IsDisplayedStandard>1</IsDisplayedStandard>
                  <IsLoyaltyOnly>0</IsLoyaltyOnly>
                  <OrderPricesBy>1</OrderPricesBy>
                  <TicketHasBarcode>N</TicketHasBarcode>
                  <Cinema_strID>0</Cinema_strID>
                  <Session_strID>79731</Session_strID>
                  <AreaCat_strCode>0000000001</AreaCat_strCode>
                  <AreaCat_strSeatAllocationOn>Y</AreaCat_strSeatAllocationOn>
                  <Cinema_strID1>0</Cinema_strID1>
                  <Price_strTicket_Type_Code>0001</Price_strTicket_Type_Code>
                  <Price_strTicket_Type_Description>Standard</Price_strTicket_Type_Description>
                  <Price_strGroup_Code>7010</Price_strGroup_Code>
                  <Price_intTicket_Price>1400000</Price_intTicket_Price>
                  <Price_strChild_Ticket>N</Price_strChild_Ticket>
                  <AreaCat_strCode1>0000000001</AreaCat_strCode1>
                  <AreaCat_intSeq>1</AreaCat_intSeq>
                  <Price_strTicket_Type_Description_2 />
                  <Price_strPackage>N</Price_strPackage>
                  <TType_strAvailLoyaltyOnly>N</TType_strAvailLoyaltyOnly>
                  <TType_strHOCode>ST00000001</TType_strHOCode>
                  <Price_strRedemption>N</Price_strRedemption>
                  <Price_strComp>N</Price_strComp>
                  <TType_strSalesChannels>;CALL;CELL;GSALE;IVR;KIOSK;PDA;POS;POSBK;RSP;WWW;</TType_strSalesChannels>
                  <Price_strATMAvailable>Y</Price_strATMAvailable>
                  <TType_strShowOnPOS>Y</TType_strShowOnPOS>
                  <Price_intSurcharge>0</Price_intSurcharge>
                  <TType_intBarcodeMaxRepeats>1</TType_intBarcodeMaxRepeats>
                  <TType_strMaxRepeatsCycle>O</TType_strMaxRepeatsCycle>
                  <TType_strLongDescription />
                  <TType_strLongDescriptionAlt />
                  <TType_strMemberCard>N</TType_strMemberCard>
                  <TType_strAvailRecognitionOnly />
                  <HOPK />
                  <AreaCat_strDesc>STANDARD</AreaCat_strDesc>
                  <AreaCat_strDescAlt />
                  <MMC_strName />
                  <Price_strIsTicketPackage>N</Price_strIsTicketPackage>
                  <OrderTicketsBy>1</OrderTicketsBy>
                  <TicketCategory>STANDARD</TicketCategory>
               </Table>
               <Table>
                  <IsPaid>0</IsPaid>
                  <AvailableOnSalesChannel>0</AvailableOnSalesChannel>
                  <IsDisplayedStandard>0</IsDisplayedStandard>
                  <IsLoyaltyOnly>0</IsLoyaltyOnly>
                  <OrderPricesBy>6</OrderPricesBy>
                  <TicketHasBarcode>N</TicketHasBarcode>
                  <Cinema_strID>0</Cinema_strID>
                  <Session_strID>79731</Session_strID>
                  <AreaCat_strCode>0000000001</AreaCat_strCode>
                  <AreaCat_strSeatAllocationOn>Y</AreaCat_strSeatAllocationOn>
                  <Cinema_strID1>0</Cinema_strID1>
                  <Price_strTicket_Type_Code>0002</Price_strTicket_Type_Code>
                  <Price_strTicket_Type_Description>Complimentary</Price_strTicket_Type_Description>
                  <Price_strGroup_Code>7010</Price_strGroup_Code>
                  <Price_intTicket_Price>0</Price_intTicket_Price>
                  <Price_strChild_Ticket>N</Price_strChild_Ticket>
                  <AreaCat_strCode1>0000000001</AreaCat_strCode1>
                  <AreaCat_intSeq>1</AreaCat_intSeq>
                  <Price_strTicket_Type_Description_2 />
                  <Price_strPackage>N</Price_strPackage>
                  <TType_strAvailLoyaltyOnly>N</TType_strAvailLoyaltyOnly>
                  <TType_strHOCode />
                  <Price_strRedemption>N</Price_strRedemption>
                  <Price_strComp>Y</Price_strComp>
                  <TType_strSalesChannels>;POS;POSBK;</TType_strSalesChannels>
                  <Price_strATMAvailable>Y</Price_strATMAvailable>
                  <TType_strShowOnPOS>Y</TType_strShowOnPOS>
                  <Price_intSurcharge>0</Price_intSurcharge>
                  <TType_intBarcodeMaxRepeats>1</TType_intBarcodeMaxRepeats>
                  <TType_strMaxRepeatsCycle>O</TType_strMaxRepeatsCycle>
                  <TType_strLongDescription />
                  <TType_strLongDescriptionAlt />
                  <TType_strMemberCard>N</TType_strMemberCard>
                  <TType_strAvailRecognitionOnly />
                  <HOPK />
                  <AreaCat_strDesc>STANDARD</AreaCat_strDesc>
                  <AreaCat_strDescAlt />
                  <MMC_strName />
                  <Price_strIsTicketPackage>N</Price_strIsTicketPackage>
                  <OrderTicketsBy>3</OrderTicketsBy>
                  <TicketCategory>VOUCHER</TicketCategory>
               </Table>
            </NewDataSet>
         </DatasetXML>
      </GetTicketTypeListResult>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: And if you do `print_r($xml);` what do you have

Comment: SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)

Comment: this is http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php traversable object you need loop for get value for this object

Comment: is there no way to convert it all to json?

Comment: This is not just XML but SOAP. Use the ext/soap extension.